# Making dynamic hyperlinks execute vbscript

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dynamic, hyperlink, vbscript

I am making a web app based in asp.net and backed in vb in which information is being displayed for a user based on a search criteria (for test purposes, I have been using phone numbers). I realized that some of the people in our database have the same phone number. I want to make it so that when a phone number is entered in the search, it returns the information relevant to the person connected to that number. But if there are multiple people attached to the same number, I want to dynamically create hyperlinks with the names of those people so that the user can select which person they are meaning to reference. I am so far able to create the hyperlinks with the appropriate names. What I need to do is make it so that when the hyperlink is clicked, I can execute more visual basic code to display the information necessary. I have already tried

```
b = list of names connected to phone number

For h = 0 To b.Count - 1

lblOutput.Text += "<a href='vbscript:hl" & h & "press' name='hl" & h & "'>" & b(h).FirstName & " " & b(h).LastName & "</a><br>"

lblOutput.Text += "<script type='text/vbscript'><br>"
lblOutput.Text += "sub hl" & h & "press()<br>"
lblOutput.Text += "MsgBox('Hello World')<br>"
lblOutput.Text += "end sub<br>"
lblOutput.Text += "</script><br>"
Next
```

I have also tried to feed the label an asp style Hyperlink which worked even less successfully. Any tips, help, or links would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: your going to need an engine to run the script, webbrowser would do it, but its going to prompt you with many security issues

Answer (score 0):

you can run vbs scripting in c#, BUT for html rending, not really, again your going to need something to render your html , like the webbrowser control

```
Type scriptType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(Guid.Parse("0E59F1D5-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC"));

dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(scriptType, false);
obj.Language = "vbscript";
string vbscript = "msgbox(\"test\")";
obj.Eval(vbscript);
```